# De que manera se puede evitar que los estilos de un elemento creado con javascript se confunda con los estilos de la pagina

Tags: javascript

Es que resulta que estoy creando una especie de plugin para cualquier tipo de pagina web que consiste en un chatbot, un asistente para la recoleccion de datos de los usuarios, que pregunta nombre, apellidos y correo, y telefono, y lo importo nada mas poniendo un script en la pagina ya que creo todo el chat con la funcion `createElement()` de Javascript, y cree una hoja de estilos la cual tambien la inserto mediante esta funcion, basicamente, es una inyeccion de HTML en la pagina, una inyeccion de estilos para que pueda funcionar, pero sucede que los estilos del plugin se confunden muchas veces con los estilos de la pagina, y no quiero esto, quiero que los estilos de la pagina se quede con su estilos, y los de chat, se mantengan los que yo le he puesto. Ya intente colocandole el `!important` a todas las propiedades de la hoja de estilos del plugin pero nada, no pasa nada, sigue igual.

Comment: necesito como encapsular el javascript, los css y el html del plugin, como una caja a donde los estilos de la pagina donde lo ponga no lo pueda alcanzar, eso es relamente lo que quier hacer

Comment: Podrías introducirlo en un iframe. De esta forma incluso podrías cargarlo desde una url externa: `<iframe src="http://....`

Comment: ¿Dónde usas `!important`? Si aplicas estilos directamente al elemento, eso tiene ya más peso que cualquier clase. Creo que algo estás haciendo mal...

Comment: no puedo hacerlo en un frame por que es un chat con pocision fixed en el bottom, algo asi como las ventanitas de chat de facebook, y lo del important lo aplico en todos las propiedades de la hoja de de estilos, pero no los carga asi tal cual

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve] del problema para que podamos verlo?